# Check if object key exists in array of object and add if not exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

Do you know guys how to do it simplier/smarter ?

I wanna add a label `key` with name value if the key doesn't exist in object. This is my list:

```
myList = [
    {
        name: 'Candy',
        label: 'xx',
    },
    {
        name: 'Mike',
        label: 'yy',
    },
    {
        name: 'Betty',
    }
]
```

And my solution:

```
assignLabel = list => {
        const casesWithoutLabel = list.filter(({ label }) => !label).map(item => ({
            ...item,
            label: item.name
        }))

        const casesWithLabel = list.filter(({ label }) => label)

        return [ ...casesWithoutLabel, ...casesWithLabel ]
}

assignLabel(myList)
```

Output

```
[
    {
        name: 'Candy',
        label: 'xx',
    },
    {
        name: 'Mike',
        label: 'yy',
    },
    {
        name: 'Betty',
        label: 'Betty'
    }
]
```

It gives me good output, but it's not elegant and I don't have idea how to improve now. Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have create simple script for you, please have a look!

```js
let myList = [
    {
        name: 'Candy',
        label: 'xx',
    },
    {
        name: 'Mike',
        label: 'yy',
    },
    {
        name: 'Betty',
    }
];

let list = myList.map((item) => {
  let {name, label} = item;
  if(label == undefined){
    item["label"] = name;
  }
  return item;
});

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Your Welcome! Happy to hear!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems very advanced for only assigning a property, so maybe I am missing something, but you could simply loop through the list (or filter oc)

```js
myList = [{name: 'Candy',label: 'xx',},{name: 'Mike',label: 'yy',},{name: 'Betty',}];

for(const obj of myList)
    if(!obj.label)obj.label = obj.name;
 
console.log(myList);
```